# jQuery DateTimePicker + AngularJS ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, heroku

I am using AngularJS with Yeoman, Grunt and Bower. To make one of my forms more user-friendly, I decided to use the DateTimePicker jQuery plugin (http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/). Everything works in local server, but after pushing to heroku, I get a "ReferenceError: obj is not defined" in Chrome in "f32148ce.vendor.js" which seems to be related to the Date.createParser() function.

The app: http://legends.herokuapp.com/

I am currently simply adding the jQuery scripts to the list of scripts in my index.html file along with my controllers in services as such:

```
<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/trans.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/plume.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/res.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/request.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/game.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/auth.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/auth.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/user.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/xeditable.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/resistance.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

My guess is that this is not the correct way to do this?

My datetimepicker jQuery call in my controller:
`jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();`

Here is the error message in Firefox:

```
"Error: assignment to undeclared variable obj
Date.createParser@http://legends.herokuapp.com/scripts/dc3edbf2.scripts.js:2:24855
Date.parseDate@http://legends.herokuapp.com/scripts/dc3edbf2.scripts.js:2:24243
c@http://legends.herokuapp.com/scripts/dc3edbf2.scripts.js:2:2084
a.fn.datetimepicker/B@http://legends.herokuapp.com/scripts/dc3edbf2.scripts.js:2:18746
a.fn.datetimepicker/<@http://legends.herokuapp.com/scripts/dc3edbf2.scripts.js:2:20476
.each@http://legends.herokuapp.com/scripts/f32148ce.vendor.js:1:14157
eb.prototype.each@http://legends.herokuapp.com/scripts/f32148ce.vendor.js:1:12005
a.fn.datetimepicker@http://legends.herokuapp.com/scripts/dc3edbf2.scripts.js:2:19796
@http://legends.herokuapp.com/scripts/dc3edbf2.scripts.js:2:29857
d@http://legends.herokuapp.com/scripts/f32148ce.vendor.js:4:16965
e@http://legends.herokuapp.com/scripts/f32148ce.vendor.js:4:17044
Rb/this.$get</<@http://legends.herokuapp.com/scripts/f32148ce.vendor.js:5:1
f/<.link@http://legends.herokuapp.com/scripts/f32148ce.vendor.js:8:23699
s@http://legends.herokuapp.com/scripts/f32148ce.vendor.js:4:27001
h@http://legends.herokuapp.com/scripts/f32148ce.vendor.js:4:23074
A/<@http://legends.herokuapp.com/scripts/f32148ce.vendor.js:4:22688
D/d@http://legends.herokuapp.com/scripts/f32148ce.vendor.js:4:23515
n@http://legends.herokuapp.com/scripts/f32148ce.vendor.js:4:25469
k@http://legends.herokuapp.com/scripts/f32148ce.vendor.js:8:1
Cc/this.$get</k.prototype.$broadcast@http://legends.herokuapp.com/scripts/f32148ce.vendor.js:5:26772
m/<@http://legends.herokuapp.com/scripts/f32148ce.vendor.js:8:22279
Ac/h/g.promise.then/k@http://legends.herokuapp.com/scripts/f32148ce.vendor.js:5:19641
Ac/h/g.promise.then/k@http://legends.herokuapp.com/scripts/f32148ce.vendor.js:5:19641
Ac/i/<.then/<@http://legends.herokuapp.com/scripts/f32148ce.vendor.js:5:20328
Cc/this.$get</k.prototype.$eval@http://legends.herokuapp.com/scripts/f32148ce.vendor.js:5:25534
Cc/this.$get</k.prototype.$digest@http://legends.herokuapp.com/scripts/f32148ce.vendor.js:5:24050
Cc/this.$get</k.prototype.$apply@http://legends.herokuapp.com/scripts/f32148ce.vendor.js:5:25862
i@http://legends.herokuapp.com/scripts/f32148ce.vendor.js:5:4878
r@http://legends.herokuapp.com/scripts/f32148ce.vendor.js:5:7221
_b/</w.onreadystatechange@http://legends.herokuapp.com/scripts/f32148ce.vendor.js:5:7776
" "<div class="container ng-scope" ng-view="">"
```

Comment: Have you included jquery library?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. It works locally, but not in production.

Comment: The problem was the order of my scripts, I needed to place the datetimepicker before my app.js directive.